# Implementing like functionality in AngularJS without re-downloading whole content again when clicked

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I created an app where user can like images. After a like the like-count has to increase by one.

The issue is that the whole content of the app (around 20 items (text, images)) are re-downloaded which makes the app unresponsive, especially on mobile networks.

I know that the view of AngularJS is based on the model, but is there any better way to handle a "simple like functionality" without reloading the whole content for a like-count update?

Comment: Can you share some of your code? It would help us understand what is going wrong. As pointed out by Tamas, this is not default behaviour and it shouldn't happen unless you tell Angular explicitly to reload.

Answer (score 0):

The point of AngularJS is not having to reload the whole page. I can't even think of a way how could you achieve a full page reload without explicitly commanding angularjs to do so. For example this little application will do it without a page reload:

```js
angular.module("App", [])
.service("LikeService", function($http, $q, $timeout) {
  function getLikeCount() {
    // return $http.get("/api/yourLikeCountGetterApi").then(response => response.data);
    
    // Simulate the endpoint with returning a random number between 0..50 after 1 secs
    return $timeout(angular.noop, 1000).then(() => (Math.random() * 50)|0);
  }
  
  function sendLike() {
    // return $http.post("/api/yourLikeCountIncreaseApi");
    
    return $timeout(angular.noop, 500).then(() => {
      // simulate occasional failure by 20% chance
      if (Math.random() < 0.2) {
        return $q.reject({});
      }
    });
  }
         
  return { getLikeCount, sendLike };
})
.controller("MyController", function($scope, LikeService) {
  $scope.likeCount = 0;
  $scope.loaded = false;
  
  LikeService.getLikeCount().then(count => {
    $scope.likeCount = count;
  }).finally(() => {
    $scope.loaded = true;
  });
  
  $scope.doLike = () => {
    $scope.likeCount++;
    LikeService.sendLike().then(null, error => {
      // in case of an error, revert local increase
      $scope.likeCount--;
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div>Like count: {{ loaded ? likeCount : "..." }}</div>
    <button ng-click="doLike()">LIKE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With reload I meant getting the data again from the backend and bind it to the view ($scope.data = data).